# How to test spring security for REST APIs?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, xss, csrf

I am currently working on spring-security and I also have a few APIs where in, I need to provide security to those APIs such that it will be restricted from XSS or any other kind of attacks.

I followed [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/headers.html) link to implement it.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends
WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    // ...
    .headers()
        .xssProtection()
            .block(false);
}
}
```

How can I check if this configuration is working?

Am I following the correct procedure?

Comment: you can check it with the ZAP app.

Comment: @ElTête Sorry for delay, I have tried using ZAP app. But, unable to test individual API. I want to test API with GET/POST/PUT method. Unfortunately there is no option provided to attack API with custom method and header.

Comment: Ah okay, take a look at [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop) ;)

Comment: @ElTête I'm aware of postman. But, I am unaware of testing it with vulnerabilities. Actually, that is why I am looking for a tool.